# What's the difference between "getting worse and worse" and "getting worse by the day"?

Tags: word-meaning

And, also in which alternative is the use correct?

A) While TV showed the inaugurations of costly, lavish football stadiums, people felt their lives **were getting worse and worse**. After all, the World Cup will cost the range some $ 15 billions, and the promised legacy in infrastructure is still nowhere to be seen.

B) While TV showed the inaugurations of costly, lavish football stadiums, people felt their lives **were getting worse by the day**. After all, the World Cup will cost the range some $ 15 billions, and the promised legacy in infrastructure is still nowhere to be seen.

Comment: Note that standard syntax requires *the World Cup will cost **in** the range **of** [a specific range]*. You can't just follow ***range*** with ***some $15 billion***, because that's a "single" value, not a range (and we don't normally pluralize ***billion***).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of these are correct and indicate the same idea, that people feel their lives are getting worse over time. The latter puts a specific time frame on the worsening, namely, that today is noticeably worse than yesterday, and tomorrow will be noticeably worse than today. The phrasing of "getting worse and worse" could mean the exact same thing, but is a bit more vague in the time frame of the worsening - it could be a slow decline over the course of months or years, a day-by-day progression, or something even faster.

Comment: It could be getting worse *by the minute*. Not to mention several thousand written instances where something was [*getting worse by the **second**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22getting+worse+by+the+second%22) I couldn't find anything in Google Books for anything [*getting worse by the **century**,*](https://rationallyspeaking.blogspot.com/2005/08/katrina-bush-and-global-warming.html) but that's at least one instance of it on the Internet at large.